# Удаление разделов реестра в цикле

Tags: c#, реестр

Подскажите можно как-нибудь удалить разделы реестра используя `List<string>` ?

```
static List<string> LoggerSearch = new List<string>()
{
    @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Logger",
    @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Logger"
};
```

Если стандартно используется такая схема:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(LoggerPath, true);
```

Почему именно в цикле? ( отвечаю )

У меня не получается удалить 2 раздела реестра в такой последовательности:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(LoggerPath, true);
Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree(LoggerPath, true);
```

Если только использовать для каждого try/catch но как-то это не культурно =)

---

P.S: Как прогнать в цикле `for` список `LoggerSearch`

В таком виде: `Registry.DeleteSubKeyTree(LoggerSearch[i]);` ?

Comment: просто оставлю это тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e5kx5x6a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rdorn, читал =) Но может можно как-нибудь прогнать через `List<string>`

Comment: Так и прогнать, данный метод хочет получить удаляемый ключ в виде строки, в цикле оборачиваете вызов метода в try... и подсовываете ему строки из вашего списка. В foreach заверните, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: @rdom, Я немного запутался, не знаю как работать в цикле с реестром, точнее как ему записать типа `Registry.DeleteSubKeyTree` без `LocalMachine`  =)

Comment: все, понял, вернусь напишу, добавьте уточнение в вопрос, может еще кто отпишется, раньше меня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Logger";
string[] hiveAndName = keyName.Split(new[]{'\\'}, 2);
RegistryKey root;
if ("HKEY_CURRENT_USER".Equals(hiveAndName[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) root = Registry.CurrentUser;
// else if ... // TODO
root.DeleteSubKeyTree(hiveAndName[1], false);
```

Так же нужно не забывать что 2-ой параметр должен быть false).

С использованием циклов:

```
for (var j = 0; j < LoggerSearch.Count; j++)
{
   string[] hiveAndName = LoggerSearch[j].Split(new[] { '\\' },2);
   if("HKEY_CURRENT_USER".Equals(hiveAndName[0],StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
      root = Registry.CurrentUser;
      root.DeleteSubKeyTree(hiveAndName[1], false);
   }
   else if ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE".Equals(hiveAndName[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
      root = Registry.LocalMachine;
      root.DeleteSubKeyTree(hiveAndName[1], false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Можно было использовать StartsWith в условии, вместо Split с его накладными расходами по памяти

Answer (score 1):

**1. Плохая новость**

.NET не предоставляет средств простым и удобным способом перебирать произвольные ключи из произвольных кустов реестра. В пределах одного куста (например HKLM) - пожалуйста, если нужны разные кусты - нет. WMI - тоже самое.

Если нужно работать только с указанными в вопросе двумя ключами реестра - то лучшим вариантом будет именно тот, который вам не нравится, а именно: завернуть обращение к ключам из каждого куста реестра в try...catch и вызвать последовательно.

**2. Относительно хорошая новость**

Если все таки очень хочется цикл (например для длинных списков ключей) и не хочется обрабатывать каждый куст по-отдельности, то один вариант есть.

Можно использовать консольную команду [REG DELETE](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc742145(v=ws.10).aspx) для работы с реестром прямо из приложения. В коде это может выглядеть так:

```
foreach(var key in LoggerSearch)
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("REG", $"DELETE {key} /f");
    //ключ /f подавляет запрос подтверждения операции
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;//глушим мелькание консоли
    Process.Start(psi);
}
```

На ваше усмотрение, можно перенаправить стандартный поток вывода в файл или еще куда-нибудь, и фиксировать текстовые сообщения о результатах операции. Также можно узнать результат завершения операции если дождаться окончания выполнения процесса и прочитать его свойство `Process.ExitCode`, только не пытайтесь его читать сразу после выполнения `Process.Start`, это приведет к исключению, оно доступно только после завершения процесса.

В общем-то таким не слишком хитрым способом с помощью утилиты [REG](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc732643(v=ws.10).aspx) можно выполнять в реестре все. Мне такой способ не нравится, но он работает, выбирать вам.

Comment: Уже нашёл решение)

Comment: Кстати у Вас разве не должно быть знака доллара  `$` перед `"DELEDE"`?

Comment: @Gooliver спасибо, поправил